# Does frequentist regressions also have an equivalent to posterior?

Tags: regression, bayesian

I have worked a bit with bayesian regression and I quite like its posterior data table, which offers much flexibility. E.g. plotting the results of multiple models in one graph.

Does frequentist methods also have such an option?

Comment: Please clarify what "such an option" is intended to refer to.  Currently, it looks like you could be asking about reviewing multiple models, plotting something, or something vaguely analogous to a posterior distribution, but it's unclear what.